# jQuery body load with Sinatra / Haml

Tags: jquery, sinatra

The following output is generated via a `Haml` layout file and `index.haml` from within `Sinatra`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Meeting</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport' />
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js'></script>
    <link href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
          setTimeout(getUpdate,10000);
          function getUpdate(){
            $("body").load("/");
          }
        })
      //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>Some text</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to replace `body` with a call to root `/' but if it is an AJAX call, my code at`/`checks for it and theoretically should only replace what's in`body` but instead it replaces the entire document.

Here's my `Sinatra` & `Haml` Ruby code

```
get '/' do
  ... set some instance vars to be displayed in index.haml ...
  haml :index, :layout => (request.xhr? ? false : :layout)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's "replaces the entire document". I noticed that you are using jQuery Mobile library. If the symptom is the style or layout disappears, I think the problem is jQuery Mobile.

jQuery Mobile will automatically modify your DOM structure. If you try to inspect the DOM element in your browser, you will see something like:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/test.html" tabindex="0" 
  class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 737px; ">
  Some text
</div>
```

If you replace the entire `body` element, it will definitely makes jQuery Mobile broken.

On the other hand, you don't need to use jQuery `load` function for XHR request. Please take a look at this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html :

> To enable animated page transitions, all links that point to an external page (ex. products.html) will be loaded via Ajax. To do this unobtrusively, the framework parses the link's href to formulate an Ajax request (Hijax) and displays the loading spinner. All this happens automatically by jQuery Mobile.

If you uses jQuery Mobile, you should follow the jQuery Mobile way. Otherwise, you can remove jQuery Mobile and use your own XHR mechanism.

Comment: By "replaces the entire document", I mean the entire HTML output above is replaced by `some text` when the jQuery method is called, there is no `html`, `head`, or even `script` code. Actually I didn't setup the jQuery Mobile `div`s yet, so it's not a problem as you described.

Comment: What browser do you use? How did you observe DOM change? By Chrome element inspector or Firebug? Even if you didn't setup jQuery Mobile divs, it will automatically modify your DOM structure as long as you load the jQuery mobile javascript.